# ¿Cómo obtener un JSON desde Android de un servidor local?

Tags: android, json, http

Soy nuevo en Android y algunas cosas me cuestan un poco aprender. Lo que quiero hacer es obtener desde Android un *JSON* por medio de un servidor que estoy ejecutando pero no lo puedo obtener. Lo raro es que cuando le asigno una URL externa, el *JSON* lo puedo obtener (de ahí el título de la pregunta).
No tengo ningún mensaje que me está indicando algún error en el Event Log.
El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
       queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       String URL = "http://localhost:8080/miEndPoint";
       JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                           try {
                               for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                                   JSONObject mJsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                   String name = mJsonObject.getString("nombre");
                                   //Toast.makeText(Conf.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                           } catch (JSONException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           }
       });
           queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

y lo que estoy obteniendo en el logcat es lo siguiente:

```
2020-07-01 18:51:17.730 7311-7311/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2020-07-01 18:51:48.114 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup36: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:51:48.118 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:51:54.205 7311-7311/? E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places [CONTEXT service_id=111 ]
2020-07-01 18:51:58.421 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup36: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:51:58.427 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:53:09.247 408-408/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-07-01 18:53:09.247 412-412/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2020-07-01 18:53:15.901 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup36: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:53:15.910 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:53:17.539 347-7807/? E/ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
2020-07-01 18:53:18.503 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup36: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:53:18.522 255-260/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-07-01 18:53:18.878 545-632/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'c345fe4 Splash Screen com.example.animations (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

¿Alguna sugerencia por qué puede ser? Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Comment: Los mensajes del Logcat hacen pensar que te está bloqueando la conexión remota en el puerto `8080`, mira esto por ejemplo: *`Connection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe`*, en tu PC debes autorizar conexiones a ese puerto.

Comment: Sería interesante que pongas un Log en el bloque `onErrorResponse` para ver si arroja otro tipo de información ahi.

Comment: Hola, disculpa y como haria para autorizar las conexiones al puerto 8080? Tendría que configurarlo dentro del firewall?. Y con lo que me decis del mensaje de Log, a que tipo de mensaje te referis? Mucho no entiendo el funcionamiento del LogCat

Comment: Puedes algo así más o menos en el bloque de control de erroes de Volley: `@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
 Log.d("ErrorVolley", "Mensaje: \t" + error.getMessage());
 Log.d("ErrorVolley", "Traza de la pila: \t" + error.getStackTrace());
}` Luego revisas el Logcat y al lado de `ErrorVolley` te deberían aparecer dos mensajes de error específicos sobre la petición Volley.

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver es lo que dijiste. Los mensajes que tengo son:
 `D/ErrorVolley: Mensaje:  java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080` **y** `D/ErrorVolley: Traza de la pila:  [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@88c7977`.
Ahora veo si encuentro alguna solución a esto..

Comment: Ahi lo pude solucionar, era algo muy sencillo. No entendí bien por qué pero reemplace localhost por la ip local de mi maquina y anduvo jaja. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: [Aquí se ha tratado largamente](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5806220/5587982) ese tema, por si te interesa.